# Spring batch Writer to write files directly to ftp location,

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to read,process,writer and create files directly from FTP location.
I could able to read files using below configration.

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReader2" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <!-- Read a csv file -->
<property name="resource" 
value="ftp://user123:12496@ftp.myftp.net/Ftpfiles/it/se/dev/expfiles/ABEXCEP.CSV"/>
```

But the same i am trying to write using the FlatFileItemWriter uaing below config

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
<property name="resource" value="ftp://user123:12496@ftp.myftp.net/Ftpfiles/it/se/dev/expfiles/ABFIXED.TXT" />
```

Getting the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException:
  URL [ftp://user123:12496@ftp.myftp.net/Ftpfiles/it/se/dev/expfiles/ABFIXED.TXT]
  cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system:
  ftp://user123:12496@ftp.myftp.net/Ftpfiles/it/se/dev/expfiles/ABFIXED.TXT
  at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:205)
```

Appreciate any help on this.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can't create a remote FTP `Resource`. One solution consist on using **Spring Batch** to generate your file, Then you can use [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/)'s [FTP/FTPS Adapters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html) to transfer your generated file to the FTP server.

Hope could help you.

Comment: as per my analysis spring integration also creating files locally and sending to ftp location as in separate tasklet? i need to create and write data directly to ftp location

Comment: Spring integration is totally independant from Spring batch. Consider it as a daemon, that will check if there a new generated file on your batch writer's destination directory. If it's the case, it will send it to your ftp server.

Answer (score 3):

Springs org.springframework.core.io.Resource has a sub-interface that is called org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource for which the only implementations I found were: FileSystemResource and FileSystemContextResource. So it's not possible to write straight on ftp. What you can do is write locally on disk and write a tasklet that upload from disk to ftp.

Answer (score 1):

Use spring-integration for this type of job (see [this example](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/09/send-data-secure-with-sftp-and-spring-batch/)) for further explanation

Comment: This example also creating files locally and sending to ftp location as in separate tasklet? i need to create and write data directly to ftp location.

Answer (score 0):

Use Tasklet to send file over sftp. Refer this [link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/09/send-data-secure-with-sftp-and-spring-batch/), [link](http://blog.luventas-webdesign.de/2011/09/05/secure-data-sending-with-sftp-and-spring-batch/) for more information / coding for this.